# Storage reuse Undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, stdlaunder

Reading in the cppreference for [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime), there is the following statement for storage reuse

> A program is not required to call the destructor of an object to end
> its lifetime if the object is trivially-destructible or if the program
> does not rely on the side effects of the destructor. However, if a
> program ends the lifetime of an non-trivially destructible object that
> is a variable explicitly, it must ensure that a new object of the same
> type is constructed in-place (e.g. via placement new) before the
> destructor may be called implicitly, i.e. due to scope exit or
> exception for automatic objects, due to thread exit for thread-local
> objects, or due to program exit for static objects; otherwise the
> behavior is undefined.

There is the following example

```
class T {}; // trivial
 
struct B
{
    ~B() {} // non-trivial
};
 
void x()
{
    long long n; // automatic, trivial
    new (&n) double(3.14); // reuse with a different type okay
} // okay
 
void h()
{
    B b; // automatic non-trivially destructible
    b.~B(); // end lifetime (not required, since no side-effects)
    new (&b) T; // wrong type: okay until the destructor is called
} // destructor is called: undefined behavior
```

Why when the destructor of T is called is undefined behavior?

In the above example, if std::launder is used , is the UB issue solved? Look at the following [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/axeEhcYq8)

Comment: why would the destructor of T be called?

Comment: (1) create `b`; (2) manually end the lifetime of `b`; (3) create a `T` in the storage for `b`; (4) end-of-scope `b` is automatically destructed but there is a `T` where a `B` should be - UB.  The destructor of `T` is not called but the destructor of `B` is called at end-of-scope.

Comment: The section tells you what happens if you were to do this. So now you know not to do that! The rule is probably only useful when implementing some complicated library types. Not for user code.

Comment: In the above example, if std::launder is used , is the UB issue solved? Look at the following demo  https://godbolt.org/z/axeEhcYq8  @BoP

Comment: std::launder might help you get a valid pointer to the created object (unclear if it is necessary though). But you still have UB at the closing brace when B's destructor is invoked - but there is no B.